# device (enp9s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')

Tags: linux, networking, fedora

On Fedora-38, as root, I tried:
`$ nmcli device connect enp9s0`
which is 'Wired connection 2' and got the following using:

```
$ journalctl -b -u NetworkManager

Jul 04 17:20:04 Level10 NetworkManager[1811]: <info>  [1688516404.0854] dhcp4 (enp9s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Jul 04 17:20:04 Level10 NetworkManager[1811]: <info>  [1688516404.0855] dhcp4 (enp9s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jul 04 17:20:04 Level10 NetworkManager[1811]: <info>  [1688516404.0855] dhcp4 (enp9s0): state changed no lease
Jul 04 17:20:26 Level10 NetworkManager[1811]: <info>  [1688516426.9886] agent-manager: agent[dcb1b81bbec4cc63,:1.945/nmcli-connect/0]: agent registered
Jul 04 17:20:26 Level10 NetworkManager[1811]: <info>  [1688516426.9894] device (enp9s0): Activation: starting connection 'Wired connection 2' (db7b61ca-c55d-39a0-bd3d-1b6bb4d3319e)
Jul 04 17:20:26 Level10 NetworkManager[1811]: <info>  [1688516426.9895] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="db7b61ca-c55d-39a0-bd3d-1b6bb4d3319e" name="Wired connection 2" pid=89931 >
Jul 04 17:20:26 Level10 NetworkManager[1811]: <info>  [1688516426.9896] device (enp9s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 04 17:20:26 Level10 NetworkManager[1811]: <info>  [1688516426.9899] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jul 04 17:20:26 Level10 NetworkManager[1811]: <info>  [1688516426.9900] device (enp9s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 04 17:20:27 Level10 NetworkManager[1811]: <info>  [1688516427.0160] device (enp9s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 04 17:20:27 Level10 NetworkManager[1811]: <info>  [1688516427.0180] dhcp4 (enp9s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jul 04 17:21:12 Level10 NetworkManager[1811]: <info>  [1688516472.0658] device (enp9s0): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 04 17:21:12 Level10 NetworkManager[1811]: <info>  [1688516472.0663] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Jul 04 17:21:12 Level10 NetworkManager[1811]: <warn>  [1688516472.0664] device (enp9s0): Activation: failed for connection 'Wired connection 2'
Jul 04 17:21:12 Level10 NetworkManager[1811]: <info>  [1688516472.0667] device (enp9s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
```

---

What can I do to get my Wired LAN I/F working (or better yet, both of them)?

I also have Wired connection 1, but it seems to be worse, given...

```
$ nmcli con show
NAME                UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE
3c58ac5             50615f69-30fd-411a-b3bd-39e0858e30a6  wifi      wlp5s0
lo                  5a3b47a1-1f41-4d71-b917-58742be80314  loopback  lo
Wired connection 1  44801890-09c3-31eb-a8aa-9f21d0b17aa9  ethernet  --
Wired connection 2  db7b61ca-c55d-39a0-bd3d-1b6bb4d3319e  ethernet  --
$ nmcli dev status
DEVICE          TYPE       STATE                   CONNECTION
wlp5s0          wifi       connected               3c58ac5
lo              loopback   connected (externally)  lo
enp9s0          ethernet   disconnected            --
p2p-dev-wlp5s0  wifi-p2p   disconnected            --
enp8s0          ethernet   unavailable             --
wgpia0          wireguard  unmanaged               --
```

---

```
$ inxi -F # tells me

Network:
  Device-1: Intel Wireless-AC 9260 driver: iwlwifi
  IF: wlp5s0 state: up mac: ...59:1F
  Device-2: Intel I211 Gigabit Network driver: igb
  IF: enp8s0 state: down mac: ...4B:88
  Device-3: Intel I211 Gigabit Network driver: igb
  IF: enp9s0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: ...4B:89
  IF-ID-1: wgpia0 state: unknown speed: N/A duplex: N/A mac: N/A
```

Disturbingly, only the MAC address for the `wlp5s0` Wi-Fi I/F `...59:1F` and a wired I/F w/MAC: ...C0:EA show up on the router's device table. Neither `enp8s0` (`...4B:88`) or `enp9s0` (`...4B:89`) make an appearance.

What could cause that?

Comment: use the `{}` editor button to make structured output readable ... and for the sake of readability don't make everything big and bold

Comment: This like shouting at us.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.